# Create a 2D array from paired elements of two 1D arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

```js
const A = [1,2,3,4,5]
const B = [6,7,8,9,10]
const C = [];
for (let j=0; j<A.length;j++){
  C[j] = C[[A[j],B[j]]
}
```

I want to create a 2D array C such that
 
`C = [[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9],[5,10]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Code:

```js
const A = [1,2,3,4,5]
const B = [6,7,8,9,10]
const C = A.map((item, index) => ([item, B[index]]));

console.log(C);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const A = [1,2,3,4,5]
const B = [6,7,8,9,10]
const C = A.map((_,i)=>[A[i],B[i]])
console.log(C);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `C[[A[j],B[j]]` correct this line. By this line you're trying to access an index `[A[j],B[j]]` in `C` which is ( `undefined` ) not what you want

```js
const A = [1,2,3,4,5]
const B = [6,7,8,9,10]
const C = [];
for (let j=0; j<A.length;j++){
 C[j] = [A[j],B[j]]
}

console.log(C)
```

Answer (score 1):

need to replace `C[j] = C[[A[j],B[j]]` with `C[j] = [A[j],B[j]]`. Because `C[[A[j],B[j]]` is `undefined`

```js
const A = [1,2,3,4,5]
const B = [6,7,8,9,10]
const C = [];
for(let j = 0;j<A.length;j++){
  C[j] = [A[j],B[j]];
}
console.log(C)
```

**Better way:** using `map()`

```js
const A = [1,2,3,4,5]
const B = [6,7,8,9,10]
const C = A.map((item, i) => ([item,B[i]]));
console.log(C);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const A = [1,2,3,4,5]
const B = [6,7,8,9,10]
const C = [];
for (let j=0; j<A.length;j++){
 C.push([A[j],B[j]]);
}
```

At the 5th line, we're creating an array of 2 values (one from A and one from B) and after that push the array into the A array.
Very simple,NO?

Comment: Using `for loop` and `Array.prototype.push()` on every loop it's not simple at all

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a transpose algorithm to switch row to column, if you take the two given arrays as a new array with rows.

```js
const
    transpose = array => array.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]), []),
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    c = transpose([a, b]);

console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```